# django url doesn't redirect properly

Tags: python, html, django

I am trying to send user to next page using button like this

```
<a href="weekly/" class="btn">Weekly Report</a>
<a href="daily/" class="btn">Daily Report</a>
```

but when I click on header or another button at daily URL keeps stacking like daily/weekly

instead /daily or /weekly. It doesn't clear URL and go to button instead just keeps adding it.

This is `url.py`

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name="Home"),
    path('weekly/', views.weekly, name="weekly"),
    path('daily/', views.daily, name="daily"),
]
```

I tried different ways to call URL like `{% url 'weekly' %}` but still it's the same.

All urls only keep stacking. even home page button does keep stacking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change to urls to either:

```
<a href="/weekly/" class="btn">Weekly Report</a>
<a href="/daily/" class="btn">Daily Report</a>
```

Or use [`{% url %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#url) tag in template:

```
<a href="{% url 'weekly' %}" class="btn">Weekly Report</a>
<a href="{% url 'daily' %}" class="btn">Daily Report</a>
```

Comment: For advising the `{% url ... %}`, +1.